# Restored TensorFlow model unexpectedly changes weights each time it is restored

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

My TensorFlow model returns different weights each time I restore it even though I am no longer training the model and the check-pointed-model-file is not changing. This is problematic because I get random and unreliable predictions with the same hard-coded input.

Below is a simplified version of my code that simply returns the sum of all the weights. The sum changes each time each time I run the script, indicating that the weights are changing.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

def weight_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
    initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
    return tf.Variable(initial)

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 240, 320, 3])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3])
x_shaped = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 240 * 320 * 3])

W1 = weight_variable([240 * 320 * 3, 32])
b1 = bias_variable([32])
h1 = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x_shaped, W1) + b1)

W2 = weight_variable([32, 3])
b2 = bias_variable([3])
y=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h1, W2) + b2)

saver = tf.train.Saver()
sess = tf.InteractiveSession(config=tf.ConfigProto())
saver.restore(sess, "/some/path/model.ckpt")
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
weights = W1.eval(session=sess)
print(np.sum(weights))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running `tf.initialize_all_variables()` **after** `saver.restore()`. This means that the values you have restored from the checkpoint will be overwritten by new initial values for each of your variables. Deleting the line `tf.initialize_all_variables()` should fix things.